# ¿Cómo inhabilitar contenido según la fecha y tipo de usuario?

Tags: php, mysqli

El detalle del contenido o producto donde muestro toda la información desde mi tabla `contenido`

```
id_contenido    contenido    title    image    author    detail    url     show_temary    active
```

y desde ella directamente puedo ocultar los capítulos este sería como contenido privado y, lo controlo desde este punto `show_temary` donde si tiene el valor de `yes` se muestra los capítulos.

```
if($show_temary ==="yes") {
    //Muestro los capítulos para usuarios registrados o otra cosa para usuarios no registrados
}
```

Ahora para usuarios registrados como cuenta de demostración se creó una nueva columna llamada `show_chapters` a la tabla `chapters` donde si el valor es `yes` se habilita ese capitulo. Bueno aquí lo puedo solucionar utilizando el mismo control del detalle del contenido o producto.

```
id_chapters    chapters    id_contenido    show_chapters
```

Pero mi mayor problema es que deseó mostrar los capítulos y, también los contenidos que abarcan dentro de los capítulos según vayan pasando los días o semanas de esa manera que se vayan habilitando los capítulos y, contenidos pero según el tipo de cuenta.

Y, mi tabla de usuarios esta conformada de la siguiente manera.

```
id_user    first_name    last_name    referred    account_type    premium_user    username    email    password    profile    logindatetime    log_in    email_code    expiry_code    active
```

Y, mi código es

```
function PlayerList(){
    global $id_contenido;
    global $conexion;

    $active = 1;
    $show_chapters = "yes";

    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_chapters,chapters FROM chapters WHERE id_contenido=? AND show_chapters=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is",$id_contenido,$show_chapters);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id_chapters, $chapters);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<h1 class="chapters-player">'.$chapters.'</h1>';

            $stmtA = $conexion->prepare("SELECT title_video,file_type_format,multimedia,detail_format_text,url_website FROM videos WHERE id_contenido=? AND id_chapters=? AND active=?");
            $stmtA->bind_param("iii",$id_contenido,$id_chapters,$active);
            $stmtA->execute();
            $stmtA->store_result();

            if ($stmtA->num_rows>0) {
                $stmtA->bind_result($title_video, $file_type_format,$multimedia,$detail_format_text,$url_website);

                while ($stmtA->fetch()) {

                }

            } else {
                echo 'Estamos trabajando para el próximo cápitulo';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'En estos momentos estamos actualizando el contenido más reciente de este cápitulo.';
    }
}
```

He logrado avanzar en ciertas cosas mencionadas, pero me gustaría poder habilitar los capítulos y, contenidos según la fecha controlando dicha acción según el tipo de cuenta me pueden explicar como realizarlo.

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el problema, ni qué quieres decir con esto: *pero me hace falta lo detallado*. ¿Nos puedes explicar con claridad y sencillez qué es lo que quieres y qué dificultad tienes?

Comment: Lou, no tengo claras las condiciones bajo las cuales se oculta o muestra el capítulo.

Comment: @JhoubertRincon Hola, he editado mi pregunta haber si está más claro :) o desde allí poder reforzar :)

Comment: Hola! En la tabla de contenido tienes una columna para guardar la fecha de ingreso de los registros? Con lo poco que entendí, creo que si tienes una columna de fecha, puedes filtrar los datos a mostrar desde el query. Considero que introduzcas un ejemplo sin código de lo que necesitas, sería fácil para nosotros ayudarte. Por ejemplo: el día hoy mostrar los 5 mas recientes, mañana, mostrar los 5 mas recientes por orden de publicación, ingreso o por lo que necesites... Espero tu comentario para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @Lou a tu pregunta le falta precisión. De momento te puedo ofrecer está sugerencia: Partir el problema para poder abordarlo 1. Crear una relación entre tipos de contenido y privilegios para facilitar la validación. 2. Una función que identifique los privilegios de usuario. 3. Otra que valide si un contenido está vinculado con algún privilegio del usuario. 4 finalmente otra para recorrer los contenidos a mostrar y enviarlos a validar si la validación devuelve 1 se muestra, o pasa al siguiente... etc.

Comment: Todavía no logro entender el problema en su totalidad. Creo que cuando el asunto es complejo hay que tratar de explicarlo con palabras sencillas, en un sólo párrafo. Intuyo que tu modelo de datos ha sido planteado de forma errónea y de ahí deriva la dificultad en la que te encuentras ahora, por lo que pregunto: ¿se podría en este momento cambiar el modelo de datos si fuere necesario? Ten en cuenta que un modelo mal planteado, cuanto antes lo cambies mejor. Si los requerimientos evolucionan y se agrega otro componente en el futuro (que te pidan filtrar por un nuevo criterio) va a ser peor.

Comment: Creo que podrías ser un poco más explicito, decir que quieres obtener y todo, porque nadamas planteas como funciona y dices obtenerlo por fechas, pero no das más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es un poco difícil entender tu explicación, pero, si no me equivoco, quieres que los capítulos se muestren según un día específico y si el usuario está registrado o no. Esta es una idea que podrías aplicar: lo primero que debes hacer es tomar el valor de `logindatetime` en la tabla de usuarios como variable global o encerrarla en un `$_SESSION['fecha_login_usuario']`, esto (imagino) te da una fecha y hora concreta que se actualiza cada vez que el usuario inicia sesión. Luego, debes crear una columna `date` en la tabla `chapters` agregando una fecha manual con el mismo formato de la columna `logindatetime`, esta fecha la programas tú al crear los capítulos.

Ahora bien, agrega antes que nada la variable global con el valor del `logindatetime` traída desde la tabla de usuarios.

```
function PlayerList(){
global $id_contenido;
global $conexion;
global $login_date;

$active = 1;
$show_chapters = "yes";
```

Cuando haces el `SELECT` desde la tabla `chapters` debes agregar la nueva columna `date`

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_chapters,chapters,date FROM chapters WHERE id_contenido=? AND show_chapters=?");
$stmt->bind_param("is",$id_contenido,$show_chapters);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

//obtienes los resultados con el date
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id_chapters, $chapters, $date);
```

En este punto puedes colocar un `if` para validar la fecha y comprobar que se pueda habilitar el capítulo:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
//Si la fecha de login es mayor o igual a la fecha de programación del capítulo
    if ($login_date => $date) {
        echo '<h1 class="chapters-player">'.$chapters.'</h1>';

        $stmtA = $conexion->prepare("SELECT title_video,file_type_format,multimedia,detail_format_text,url_website FROM videos WHERE id_contenido=? AND id_chapters=? AND active=?");
        $stmtA->bind_param("iii",$id_contenido,$id_chapters,$active);
        $stmtA->execute();
        $stmtA->store_result();

        if ($stmtA->num_rows>0) {
            $stmtA->bind_result($title_video, $file_type_format,$multimedia,$detail_format_text,$url_website);

            while ($stmtA->fetch()) {

            }

        } else {
            echo 'Estamos trabajando para el próximo capítulo';
        }
     } else { //Si la fecha de login es menor a la fecha de programación del capítulo
         echo 'Este contenido no está disponible en este momento';
     }
   }
} else { 
    echo 'En estos momentos estamos actualizando el contenido más reciente de este capitulo.';
}
```

Con esta línea de código: `$show_chapters = "yes";` ya estás validando que sean usuarios registrados con cuenta de demostración, si no me equivoco.

Espero poder ayudarte. Si tienes algún problema deja un comentario o sé más explicita en tu explicación.